# ActiveMQ Network of Brokers ERROR: java.lang.SecurityException: The destination does not exist

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue, messaging

Experts,

I have two brokers configured as part of Netowrk of brokers configuration:

**Broker1**

```
         <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
            brokerName="broker1"
            brokerId="1"
            dataDirectory="${activemq.data}"
            advisorySupport="false"
            offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="10800000"
            offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="3600000"> 
       ...      
        <networkConnectors>
          <networkConnector name="from_broker_1" networkTTL="3" userName="xxxxx" password="xxxxxxx" uri="static:(tcp://192.168.10.100:61616)"/>
        </networkConnectors>
       ...
       <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire"
                                uri="nio://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
       </transportConnectors>
       ...
```

**Broker2**

```
         <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
            brokerName="broker2"
            brokerId="1"
            dataDirectory="${activemq.data}"
            advisorySupport="false"
            offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="10800000"
            offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="3600000">
       ...
        <networkConnectors>
          <networkConnector name="from_broker_2" networkTTL="3" userName="xxxxx" password="xxxxxxx" uri="static:(tcp://192.168.10.101:61616)"/>
        </networkConnectors>
       ...
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire"
                                uri="nio://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>
       ...
```

Both the brokers are running on separate nodes and listening on port 61616.
When I try to start the brokers on respective nodes, I get the following error in activemq.log on broker1 (similar error is seen on broker2):

```
 | ActiveMQ NIO Worker 8
2017-12-17 16:17:07,707 | INFO  | Establishing network connection from vm://broker1?async=false&create=false to tcp://192.168.10.101:61616 | org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector | ActiveMQ Task-2
2017-12-17 16:17:07,708 | INFO  | Connector vm://broker1 started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ Task-2
2017-12-17 16:17:07,716 | INFO  | Network connection between vm://broker1#214 and tcp:///192.168.10.101:61616@53040 (broker2) has been established. | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | triggerStartAsyncNetworkBridgeCreation: remoteBroker=tcp:///192.168.10.101:61616@53040, localBroker= vm://broker1#214
2017-12-17 16:17:07,721 | ERROR | Network connection between vm://broker1#214 and tcp:///192.168.10.101:61616@53040 shutdown due to a remote error: java.lang.SecurityException: The destination does not exist. | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///192.168.10.101:61616@53040
2017-12-17 16:17:07,726 | INFO  | Connector vm://broker1 stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker1] Task-52
2017-12-17 16:17:07,726 | INFO  | broker1 bridge to broker2 stopped | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker1] Task-52
2017-12-17 16:17:14,853 | WARN  | Async error occurred: java.lang.SecurityException: The destination does not exist. | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: did you configured an authorizationPlugin ?

Comment: Is it required? As per the AMQ document it says "To control access to temporary destinations, you will need to add a <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry> element to the authorizationMap. Through this element, you control access to all temporary destinations. If this element is not present, read, write, and admin privileges for temporary destinations will be granted to all."?
Also, if I am reconfigure how do I go about it?

Comment: no it is only a question to check if your problem is due to this config

Comment: maybe it is better to post your whole brokers configurations if possible and all logs

Comment: Thanks @Hassan Bennour. This indeed turned out to be a problem with authorizationPlugin